# Where are my scripts?

Tags: filesystem, file

My RPi 3 model B SD card would not load after an attempt to upgrade today, which aborted part way through.  I reinstalled a fresh system on a new card and all is well.  I loaded the old card in a USB SD card adapter and plugged it into the Pi.  The file manager shows it as the /media directory and lists all of the system files and directories.  What I cannot find on it are the Python scripts I wrote.  I expected them to be in a Pi directory but they are not.  Does anyone know where I can find them.  I have some day old backups, so it is not vital, and they are only simple scripts I used to learn the system, but I am curious as to where they are.  Thanks.  BTW, I used find files in the File Manager and it does not find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change to the media directory:

```
cd /media
```

then do a directory listing:

```
ls
```

You should see a `pi` directory

change to the pi directory:

```
cd pi
```

and again do a directory listing

```
ls
```

You should see two directories a boot directory and a directory made up of a long string of letters and numbers (this may also be called root).

Change to the non boot directory:

```
cd 7f59532....
```

Note: you can just do cd and the first few characters and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>

Do another directory listing:

```
ls
```

You Should see a long list of directories including `home`

You can change to the pi directory with the following command:

```
cd /home/pi
```

You should now be in Pi's home directory on the old SD card.

Comment: Thanks.  You pointed me in the right direction.  I found them in /media/pi/root/home/pi